# What's the outbound IP address used by Bluemix?

Tags: ip-address, ibm-cloud

My app running on Bluemix needs to make HTTP calls to other services on the internet. What outbound IP address is used for these requests? How can I ensure that I am using a static IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outbound IP address will vary based on the virtual machine instance your application is running on. If you need a static IP for outbound access, you can use the Statica service from the Bluemix catalog.